# Has something that sounds like Jin-hee or jin-hae any meaning in Korean?

Tags: word-usage, translation, names, single-word-request, place-names

Do you know a vocabulary, name of a person,place...Basically anything that sounds about like what I tried to write in Latin letters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I write two words you have given,

- jin-hee is 진희 or less likely 진히
- jin-hae is 진해

First of all, 진희 a common last name especially for girls. I can't think of other use cases of 진희 other than a person's name.

진해 can be an adjective of 진하다 meaning dark, thick, deep, or strong.

It can also be a name of an administrative district in souther Korea: [진해구 Jinhae-gu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinhae-gu). If I heard 진해 without any context, I would come up with the district's name. 진해 is well known for its annual [Gunhangje](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/ATR/SI_EN_3_6.jsp?cid=1630721), a cherry blossom festival.

[image]

Comment: Jinhae is also known for being a major port of ROK Navy.  The festivel, 군항제, literally means "military port festival".